# UPS to bypass tripping a fuse?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, power

I have an apartment setup right now where one fuse has a fair amount of load on it.  (Fridge, Microwave, PC).  Rarely, when these are all used in conjunction, the fuse trips and I have to turn it back on (and I'm sure it's awful for these devices too!)  Would it be at all possible to put a UPS on the outlet, and then plug everything into the UPS instead?  That way when it's at a higher load, it falls back to the battery draining a little, instead of the fuse blowing?  Or is that not how a UPS works at all?  This is in the USA in case that matters for watts/voltage/whatever.

Comment: Kinda figured as much.  Is there any way to get around this situation in the short term?  I won't be able to get someone to add new outlets for several months.  I guess just extension cords from other outlets?  (also, feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can mark you as correct answer)

Comment: Running a circuit so close to capacity that it's tripping the safety device repeatedly (fuse or circuit breaker) is not a safe situation to be in -- the circuit is under constant overload, and you're counting on the safety device to protect you. You should split these loads across multiple circuits. I'm surprised that those 3 loads are making it trip unless you have a very power hungry PC.

Comment: I would get a Kill-a-Watt and measure each of the loads (particularly: amps at peak power) and find out what on earth is the problem.  Since you are comfortable turning off breakers (those things that are switch-like are circuit breakers not fuses), turn off one at a time and map which outlets are on which breaker (nightlights help with this). Then with your Kill-a-Watt measurements, figure how to rearrange what's plugged in where to balance stuff out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fuse is there to prevent your wires from burning up in the walls. A UPS is for a short supply of backup power when the power goes out - not to bypass the tripping of a fuse/breaker. If you're not able to move these loads to different circuits, then you shouldn't use them all at once or allow them to be used together. You don't want to bypass a safety device.

As for your second question to alleviate the problem.. Yes, you should push something off to a different circuit. However, extension cords aren't intended to replace hardwiring not for "on/off" appliances like a heater or refrigerator. Of your situation, I'd say move the computer to a different circuit or extension cord as it's not a huge load.

Comment: Yes, adding a UPS is not going to reduce the current draw of the devices. The breaker will probably still trip. You could however put the PC on a UPS to prevent restarts every time you trip the breaker. Or better yet move the PC to another circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UPS to defer some of the load while the microwave runs.  I did this as a kid.  I had only 15 amps to live on in my room, and my microwave are up a good ten of them.  So I kept a 3000kva ups charged and ready, and when I used the microwave a load sensor I installed anr programmed automatically isolated the UPS from mains and my computer ran on UPS battery while popcorn popped.  When the microwave was done, the UPS was reconnected and began recharging.

You can use a UPS to "smooth out" load, To a degree.  You're limited by the runtime of the UPS batteries.  And it's WAY better to just run a new circuit.

Run 12-gague wire, and install 20A breakers and outlets. (Or pay your landlord to do this.)  You won't regret it.

Comment: For what it's worth, most consumer grade UPS's these days are only capable of putting out enough power for a mid-range computer, and they will turn off if you try to draw too much current.  You might be able to find a UPS that will run a 1000W+ microwave, but none of the ones I have would do it, so pay attention to the specs.

Comment: Not advocating putting the microwave on UPS.  put the computer on UPS.

Comment: Ha, totally read that the wrong way...  Too early for me I guess - sorry!